# Redirect CMD.exe output to a pipe

Tags: winapi, pipe, cmd

Can I use `CreateProcess` (or `ShellExecute`, or any other means of invoking `cmd.exe` to run a batch script) and have all output redirected to a pipe owned by my process? How do I give the child cmd.exe process a handle to one of the pipe endpoints? Is it even possible to use a pipe in this way?

(Googling for variations on the terms "cmd.exe" and "pipes" is nothing but redirecting output to another program using the |(pipe) character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with .NET:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

And for C/C++:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. The link for the C/C++ example should be the easiest for me to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will help... it is in VB.NET but it shouldn't be hard to change it to C#...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/04/01/run-a-command-from-the-command-prompt-and-get-its-output-in-a-windows-application.aspx

Comment: It looks promising, but instead of a pipe output looks like it's being written to a temp file and then read.  A good backup idea to use if I can't get a pipe to work.