# Redirecting CMD.exe output and input in c through pipes

Tags: c, windows, cmd, pipe

Im trying to print the output and input of cmd commands recieved to stdout just like a normal cmd.exe would do.
I could use the function `_popen` but when i start a program like Python or Powershell whith it, it doesnt work. **So i Need the Output of the child process and be able to send commands to the child process.**

there is a simmilar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722005/redirect-cmd-exe-output-to-a-pipe)

So i modified the code from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) link to look like this:

```
void WriteToPipe(char* command){
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, command, strlen(command), &dwWritten, NULL);

    // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

    if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle"));
}

void ReadFromPipe(void){
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    //bSuccess = PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, &dwTotalAvailBytes, &dwBytesLeft);
}
```

the main loop looks like this:

```
CreateChildProcess("C:\\Python27\\python.exe");
char input_buffer[100] = { 0 };
while (1){
    fgets(input_buffer, 99, stdin);
    WriteToPipe(input_buffer);
    ReadFromPipe();
}
```

everything else (from the code) stayed the same.

Now my Problem is, i want to enter multiple commands to the same process, but there is a CloseHandle fucntion in WriteToPipe, after the handle is closed i cant enter more commands.

**How to get a valid HANDLE to write more than 1 command to the process ?**

Comment: in the function: `ReadFromPipe` the local variable `bSuccess` is set at each sub function call but is never used.  Your compiler should have told you of this problem.  When compiling, always enable all warnings, then fix the warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: since you are using windows functions, instead of using the function CreateChildProcess(), use CreateProcess of windows, then you can replace the stdin, stdout and stderr handels. you will get more controls over it. there are many tutorial about that

Comment: @user3629249 i know but its like i sayed the first 2 calls work....

Comment: @milevyo uhhmmmm CreateChildProcess is defined in my source code and actually calls CreateProcess, and yes i defined hStdOutput etc , but thx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

put ReadFromPipe() in a separate Thread;
my code here is a garbage but it is working code, it is for test purpose only.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

int CreateChildProcess(TCHAR *szCmdline);

void PrintError(char *text,int err);
int InitPipes();


int WriteToPipe(char* command){
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    SetLastError(0);
    WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, command, strlen(command), &dwWritten, NULL);


    bSuccess=GetLastError();

    PrintError("WriteToPipe",bSuccess);
    return (bSuccess==0)||(bSuccess==ERROR_IO_PENDING);
}

int ReadFromPipe(void){
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetLastError(0);
    while(
        ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL)
        &&
        WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL)
        );

    bSuccess=GetLastError();
    PrintError("ReadFromPipe",bSuccess);


    return (bSuccess==0)||(bSuccess==ERROR_IO_PENDING);
}

HANDLE hThread;

int __stdcall ThreadProc(int arg){

    while(ReadFromPipe())
        ;

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char input_buffer[100] = { 0 };
    if(!InitPipes()){
        printf("Failed to CreatePipes\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(!CreateChildProcess("cmd.exe")){
        printf("Failed to create child process\n");
        return -2;
    }


    hThread=CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadProc,NULL,0,NULL);

    while (1){
        fgets(input_buffer, 99, stdin);
        if(!WriteToPipe(input_buffer)) break;
    }
    printf("Program terminated\n");
    return 0;
}





int CreateChildProcess(TCHAR *szCmdline){ 

   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 

// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

   ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
   siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process. 

   bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
      szCmdline,     // command line 
      NULL,          // process security attributes 
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
      0,             // creation flags 
      NULL,          // use parent's environment 
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
   if (  bSuccess ){
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example. 

      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
   }
    return bSuccess;
}



int InitPipes(){
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 

// Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 



   if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
      return 0;

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      return 0;

   if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
      return 0;

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      return 0; 

    return 1;
}





void PrintError(char *text,int err){
     DWORD retSize;
     LPTSTR pTemp=NULL;

    if(!err) return;

     retSize=FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|
                           FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|
                           FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY,
                           NULL,
                           err,
                           LANG_NEUTRAL,
                           (LPTSTR)&pTemp,
                           0,
                           NULL );


    if(pTemp) printf("%s: %s\n",text,pTemp);
     LocalFree((HLOCAL)pTemp);
    return ;

}
```

Comment: Remarque the udplicate output of the input, try to fix it;

Comment: what was the result of testing it?

Comment: `WriteFile` cannot return `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, unless it is used asynchronously. Checking the return value against `ERROR_IO_PENDING` for a synchronous write operation doesn't make sense.

Comment: well, i mentioned that the code is garbage :). the main problem has been solved.

Comment: I didn't mention it, because it seemed obvious to me: Stackoverflow isn't exactly about posting garbage answers. You may wish to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out, what stackoverflow is. (It's not about posting more than one answer to a question either; there's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33131283/edit) link on your answers for a reason.)

Comment: @ IInspectable, i didn't post garbage answer, garbage answers do not resolve problems. a garbage code is not a garbage answer. it is a code that contains unnecessary code (unclean). the point is to answer the question not to deliver a well designed code. there is also the possibility to refine the code by any one who wish to participate positively. just click on edit button, i will not mind at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
int WriteToPipe(char* command){
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, command, strlen(command), &dwWritten, NULL);

   return bSuccess ;
}
```

close the handle in main() function since g_hChildStd_IN_Wr is global. also, `return bSuccess;` notify you if write to pipe has succeeded

Comment: use same thing with ReadFromPipe, check the success in main function